# Are spring.net objects created once for each server call?

Tags: spring.net

Or are they created once for the whole application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends of the scope : 
http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-scopes